# Datetime conversion in Mysql and javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, datetime

I am using javascript and Mysql to store datetime

```js
     var twoDigits = function (d) {
        if (0 <= d && d < 10) return "0" + d.toString();
        if (-10 < d && d < 0) return "-0" + (-1 * d).toString();
        return d.toString();
    };

    Date.prototype.toMysqlFormat = function () {
        return this.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + twoDigits(1 + this.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + twoDigits(this.getUTCDate()) + " " + twoDigits(this.getUTCHours()) + ":" + twoDigits(this.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + twoDigits(this.getUTCSeconds());
    };
```

So when I send "2015-07-11 10:00:00" it stores "2015-07-11 04:30:00" in DB

```
var p = new Date("2015-07-11 10:00:00").toMysqlFormat ();
```

When I retrieve this value from DB i get "2015-07-10T23:00:00.000Z".

```
Using var x = new Date("2015-07-10T23:00:00.000Z"), it gives me 

Sat Jul 11 2015 04:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

GMT here is coming wrong. It is UTC time which i am receiving. My time zone is +0530

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below in "my.cnf" file which zone u need

```
default_time_zone='+05:30' or '+00:00'
```

or

```
timezone='UTC' or 'GMT'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html